# How to get server variable via ajax/.getJSON()

Tags: c#, jquery

Righto, what I'm trying to achieve is as follows:

My OnLoad event builds a JSON string, and stores it as a variable (let's call it x)
I can then access that variable client-side as <%= x %>. All good - I have the data I need from the server on the client side.

What I don't want to do, though, is have the variable visible in the source. I want to access it via jQuery, and append it to an element, just like I could with a static file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myData.html",
    success: function (data) {
    $("#holder").html(data);      
    }
});
```

I guess what I need is to be able to substitute this line:

```
url: "myData.html",
```

with a reference to server variable x. Is that possible? I could probably use OnLoad/PageLoad to write x out to a static file, then grab that via ajax, but that seems like an unnecessary extra step. Any ideas?

N

Comment: That's the purpose of using a service, you should look at building a WCF service.  If your using WebForm's you can creaes a [WebMethod] in your page to do this, of a controller action if your using MVC.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS setup to process .js files or if this is inline js on your page you can just create a variable in javascript like:

`var serverval = '<%= Request.ServerVariable['LOCAL_ADDR'] %>';`

You could also create a hidden form element/asp:hidden and update that value in the postback/onload and reference it like:

`<input type='hidden' id='serverval' value='whatever you put ' />`
`var serverval = $('#serverval').val();`

http://forums.asp.net/t/1289684.aspx/1